# How to add and print numbers from a tokenized txt file

Tags: python-3.x, math, text, sum, multiple-columns

```
import csv

csv_file = 'Annual Budget.csv'
txt_file = 'annual_budget.txt'
with open(txt_file, 'w') as my_output_file:
with open(csv_file, 'r') as my_input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
    for row in reader:
        my_output_file.write(" ".join(row)+'\n')
        data = []

with open(r'annual_budget.txt', 'r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 header = next(reader) # this will yield first row i.e columns
 for line in reader:
     rowdata = map(float, line)
     data.extend(rowdata)
 print(sum(data)/len(data))
```

I am trying to print the sum of the columns in my CSV file turned into a txt file.I took it step by step first tokenizing the csv file, after I told my code to bypass the first line (Which would be the string headers in my file) it throws an error saying it could not convert string into float.

Output:

`data.extend(rowdata)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Answer (score 0):

Let this be an example `csv` file:

[image]

Save it as `example.csv`.

Read in the `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd   
df=pd.read_csv('example.csv',header=None)
```

Put the data to of each column to a numpy array and print the sum of each column, doing so while iterating over the columns of the file:

```
import numpy as np
for x in range(len(df.columns)):
    columndata=np.asarray(df[x])
    print(sum(columndata))
```

You get the output:

> 12.2 12 23 21